# Trying to add a listbox and a checkbox items

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, listbox

[image]When I attempt to have `CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Value`, it gives me errors. I am a bit confused and looking through this Murach ASP.Net book but I do not see any answers. I am wanting to have what is selected in my ListBox and what is selected in my CheckBox and have them added. Any help?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ucost = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        int ccost = int.Parse(//what does in here???);
        ttbox.Text = ccost.ToString();
    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
        ttbox.Text = "";
    }

    protected void ttbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

This is a an update. They say a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: do u want to get last selected item from checkboxlist?

Comment: No, what I am wanting, for example, is that lets say the user clicks on the first checkbox which is Friday Lunch. It's value is 8. I want 8 added onto the value of my listbox value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all selected checkbox, you can use:

```
var selected = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
```

If you want to get only count of selected:

```
var count = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Count(x => x.Selected)
```

If you want to get last or first element, you can use `First` or `Last` linq methods.